# How can i get the Radio buttons to reflect what is in the database when i select rows in my DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

In my Winform I have several txt fields & radio buttons and a DatagridView on the form which connect to a MySql database. I am able to enter data via the txt fields & the radio buttons which successfully enters data into the MySql database & displays it automatically in the DataGridView upon hitting the save button.  I'm also able to select individual rows in the DataGridView which displays the data in the txt fields which is great. However the radio buttons do not reflect the changes in the database e.g.... Radio button "Yes" is not checked when the database field says "Yes" and vice versa for Radio button "No"
How can i get the Radio buttons to reflect what is in the database when i select rows in my DataGridView & what is the syntax for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you asking like "RadioButton.Checked=TRUE" ?

Answer (score 1):

compare the value retrieved from database and based on whether its Yes or No set the `Checked` property of the radio button.

```
//dbValue: Database field value bound to radio button
    radioButton1.Checked = dbValue.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? true : false;
```

Comment: You don't need `? true : false` in that.

Comment: @DourHighArch Is there a way to set the `Checked` property value without explicitly setting true or false ?

Comment: Yes, set it to a value that is equal to `true` or `false`. `IEquatable.Equals` already is.

Comment: Thank you i'll give this a go & let you know how I got on.